# disable bytecode verification in java web start application

Tags: java, classloader, jnlp, java-web-start

I have a java web start application and i need to disable bytecode verification from within the jnlp file.

This can be done easily by setting JAVAWS_VM_ARGS="*-noverify*" or by setting *-Xverify:none* but the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/syntax.html#resources) here says that web start does not support adding these arguments **in jnlp file**.

I tried this :

`<j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-noverify -showversion -verbose" >`

under resources tag but it skips *-noverify* and takes the other two.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ... but the documentation here says that web start does not support adding these arguments in jnlp file.

And rightly so, IMO.  If you can disable bytecode verification, you can break JVM type-safety, and defeat the JNLP security sandbox.

---

If you have to disable bytecode verification to get your application to run, there is something seriously wrong with it.  My suggestion is to fix the problem that is causing bytecode verification to fail rather than turning it off.

Comment: I was able to run my application **with** bytecode verification but was unable to run it **after obfuscation** with verification on. Well error has been resolved now .  Many thanks :)

Comment: Yup. We were using very old version of the obfuscator. The updated version worked good.